# Is that normal behaviour of ZOTAC AMP Extreme Core Edition 1080 Ti (ZT-P10810F-10P)?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, benchmarking

1. Is it okay that ZOTAC AMP Extreme Core Edition 1080 Ti GPU with i7 7700 CPU gives:

   - 20~30FPS in Sniper Ghost Warrior 3
   - 30~40FPS in Fallout4
   - 30FPS in GTA V

*( at 4K with ultra graphics? Isn't it slow for 1080 Ti? )*

---

2. When trying to start 3DMark Basic **Fire Strike Ultra** test it runs, but crashes after random time ( sometimes it tells unknown error and sometimes it tells that user has been canceled benchmark, but it hasn't ), but only one time it finished. The result was about **2151**. Is that okay?

[image]

---

Reinstalled 3DMark, now it shows:

Fire Strike ( 1080p ):

> Local machine: **20115**;
>
> On www.tweaktown.com: **20989**;

[image: 1080p]

Fire Strike Extreme ( 2K ):

> Local machine: **8249**;
>
> On www.tweaktown.com: **12937**;

[image: 2K]

Fire Strike Ultra ( 4K ):

> Local machine: **3919**;
>
> On www.tweaktown.com: **7060**;

[image: 4K]

So, as the result, numbers **are very small** comapring them to www.tweaktown.com ( which are for AMP Extreme Edition, not AMP Extreme Core Edition ), but why? **Do these 1645 MHz - 1607 MHz ~ 38 MHz make such difference?**

**All in all, do these results are normal for ZOTAC 1080 Ti AMP Extreme Core Edition?**

Thank you very much!

Best regards

Comment: I would expect better performance from a 1080 from those 3 year old games.  The performance is what I would expect out of the iGPU.  Verify you have the Intel software uninstalled and the Nvidia software installed (current version).  A 11 GB 1080 should allow for 4K 60 FPS in GTA V

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by Intel software? I've installed GeForce Experience to update drivers, wouldn't it upgrade all stuff as supposed to?

Comment: Do you have the iGPU display drivers installed.  Like I said your performance isn’t matching that of a 1080 TI one of the best cards on the market currently (at least for another 45 days)

Comment: Yes, I do. Btw, a monitor is connected to 1080 Ti, so, does this Intel driver somehow disturbs 1080 Ti? https://i.imgur.com/gfAtgTQ.png Do I need to disable Intel video device in Device Manager?

Comment: Just uninstall the Intel display drivers

Comment: @Ramhound Although I agree that those numbers are low, I have heavy doubts that an iGPU can hit 30 FPS at 4K Ultra...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 7th generation Intel iGPUs are actually pretty powerful.  Would take no effort to try my suggestion.

Comment: @Ramhound it takes even less effort to link me to video proof. New-age iGPUs can handle roughly 720p at normal settings for those games which is moderately impressive but 4K ultra is ludicrous...